# Exim - identify recipient BCC address

Tags: exim, bcc, exim4

I'm using plus-addressing on Exim to create an automated system - I will process emails based on the local part of the address. So eg:

> **From**: me@eximdomain.com
>   **To**: robot+project-4@eximdomain.com

This works well - I can process it based on the To address (specifically project-4). But ideally I want to be able to BCC an email to this address, eg:

> **From**: me@eximdomain.com
>   **To**: somebody@otherdomain.com
>   **Bcc**: robot+project-4@eximdomain.com

When I am checking the mailbox for robot, I see the message, but nowhere in the header is the actual address that got it there, ie robot+project-4@eximdomain.com - so I cannot process it.

Obviously I do not want somebody@otherdomain.com to be aware of this address; but when robot@eximdomain.com receives it, I want to know that it was actually BCCd to robot+project-4@eximdomain.com (in some/any header).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, if anyone comes across this: added this option to my local delivery transport (Dovecot LMTP in my case):

`envelope_to_add = true`

It then generates an Envelope-to header containing the incoming address.